# Closing Mac application (clicking red cross on top), keeps app active but stops audio playback

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am working on a music player which should keep on playing music after the red cross has been pressed and it should quit when the icon has been right clicked and the quit button has been pressed. Just like iTunes does by default.

I am using the following method to keep the application running and allowing it to reopen when the icon has been pressed.

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag {

    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

    return YES;
}
```

However, this stops audio playback.

EDIT: Actually, this works. Audio playback stopped because Flash crashed.

Comment: You need to provide more detail about how the app is structured, and how you're handling audio playback. There's nothing inherent about apps on iOS that would make audio stop playing when a window is closed.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen: I think you mean "apps on Mac OS X", not iOS!

Comment: @duskwuff, doh! So I did, sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Closing window doesn't mean the app gets closed as well. See NSApplication which has a delegate method for this:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication
```

Returning NO on this method keeps the app running and thus your audio should continue playing.

Comment: This doesn't allow me to reopen the app once the red cross has been pressed.

Comment: But that does prevent stopping of the app by the red cross. You can also act as window delegate and reopen the window.